# Async request complete issue in Spring RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

Tags: spring, asynchronous, coroutine, reactive, reactor

Why does RequestMappingHandlerAdapter [call](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L903) `webRequest.requestCompleted();` even though the async request has not completed? Is that intentional? or is it a bug?

Comment: It is completed, from the pov of the current thread, it is handed of so it is now in the hands of the async stuff and not of the regular request handling thread.

Comment: @M.Deinum What does POV stand for? –

Comment: pov = Point of View.